# JQuery Slidetoggle a DIV in the next column of the table?

Tags: jquery

I have a slidetoggle that toggles a div within the same table cell, in the second column.
This works great.
But I also want clicking something in a cell of the first column of the table to toggle the same div in the second column.

I assume this is what needs to be different for the action in the first column:

```
jQuery(".heading2").click(function(){jQuery(this).next(".content2").slideToggle(500);});
```

Something like:

```
jQuery(".heading1").click(function(){jQuery(this).next(".content2" *in next column* ).slideToggle(500);});
```

The **HTML** is like this:

```
   <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="70">
        <div class="heading1">
            <img id="After Earth" src="http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/10/11171008_mob.jpg" style="border-width:0px;cursor:pointer;" />
        </div>
    </td>

    <td valign="top" align="left">

        <div class="heading2">
            <b class="title1">After Earth</b> <img id="eye771268396" src="images/eye15.png" style="border-width:0px;" class="hidepic" /><br />
            <b>Starring: </b>Will Smith, Jaden Smith, Zoe K..<br />
            <b>Director: </b><br />
        </div>

        <div class="content2">
            <b>Rating: </b>PG-13<br />
            <b>Runtime: </b>100 mins<br />
            <b>Description: </b>A crash landing leaves teenager Kitai Raige (Jaden Smith) and his legendary father Cypher (Will Smith) stranded on Earth, 1,000 years after cataclysmic events forced humanity's escape. With Cypher critically injured, Kitai must embark on a perilous journey to signal for help, facing uncharted terrain, evolved animal species that now rule the planet, and an unstoppable alien creature that escaped during the crash. Father and son must learn to work together and trust one another if they want any chance of returning home. (c) Sony<br />
        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/TWdwL/)**

```
jQuery(".heading2").click(function () {
    jQuery(this).next(".content2").slideToggle(500);
});
jQuery(".heading1").click(function () {
    jQuery(this).closest('td').next('td').find(".content2").slideToggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, from what I understand of your question:

```
jQuery('.heading1, .heading2').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('.content2').slideToggle(500);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TWdwL/1/).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).